# Elastic Beanstalk: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying my app to Elastic Beanstalk it keep returning the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'`  when it is installing the python secrets module. I had the same error on my local machine and installed PyOpenSSL to resolve it. I however keep getting this error in elastic beanstalk despite installing PyOpenSSL first in my requirements.txt file ..

error log

```
2021/03/19 11:37:57.559862 [INFO] Collecting pyOpenSSL
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-20.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting freezegun==1.1.0
  Using cached freezegun-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting pytest==6.2.2
  Using cached pytest-6.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
Collecting secrets
  Using cached secrets-1.0.2.tar.gz (7.9 kB)

2021/03/19 11:37:57.559967 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t7gr8k3l/secrets_09ec5a31c91b4f23a5c5a182f4962855/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t7gr8k3l/secrets_09ec5a31c91b4f23a5c5a182f4962855/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-azo2b_35
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-t7gr8k3l/secrets_09ec5a31c91b4f23a5c5a182f4962855/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-t7gr8k3l/secrets_09ec5a31c91b4f23a5c5a182f4962855/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import OpenSSL
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
```

requirements.txt

```
pyOpenSSL
freezegun
pytest
secrets
```

Comment: You might need the openssl development package installed on the server (e.g. via ".ebextensions" files). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages. E.g. if using yum based server, it is `openssl-devel: []`.

Comment: I have tried installing it with yum in my .ebextensions config file but I am still getting the same error ..